# Any way to guarantee a code will always be executed on the main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

Excuse me if this question sounds stupid but this is beyond my knowledge of Objective-C.

I am developing some classes that have to always be executed on the main thread.

Ok, I can pollute my code with a bunch of

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                 ^{

                 });
```

but I would like to know if there is something I can do to prevent the methods of this class from running on other threads that is not the main or to at least warn during debugging, compiling, or whatever if they are used not on the main thread.

thanks

Comment: your question is not clear. You can use GCD as you stated in your question, why this is bad for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sprinkle such methods with my [BLOCK_UI()](https://github.com/gradha/ELHASO-iOS-snippets/blob/master/src/ELHASO.h#L112) macro from https://github.com/gradha/ELHASO-iOS-snippets. At runtime the macro will assert if the method is **not** running on the main thread. The macro goes away in release builds because I consider calling such an API in the background a programmer error, but if you want to make an API which is *permissive* with the programmer, you can also check for the main thread and invoke yourself in the main thread if needed. Example:

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    [self do_request:url];
} else {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(do_request:)
        withObject:url waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Comment: I think the idea behind this BLOCK_UI() API of yours is more on the lines of what I was thinking for a solution. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can always check via the helpful API ["`[NSThread isMainThread]`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/isMainThread)